# What will happen to packages installed when the virtual environment is deleted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I create a new project with the following commands:

```
mkdir ~/my_project
python -m venv ~/my_project
source ～/my_project/Scripts/activate
pip install flask
pip install kivy
pip install foo
pip install bar
```

And let's say that I decide to remove my_project and create a new project:

```
rm -rf ~/my_project
mkdir ~/new_project
python -m venv ~/new_project
source ~/Scripts/activate
```

Questions:

- What happens to previously installed packages "flask", "kivy", "foo", and "bar"? Do I need to re-install them for my new_project's virtual environment?
- If I don't need to re-install these packages, then I am missing the point of virtual environment? I thought the whole point of virtual environment is that packages installed in the virtual environment is isolated in that environment. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Did you look at what gets stored in the virtualenv directories?

Comment: use `pip freeze` to check which packages are installed

Comment: Better use `pip list` when your virtual env is activated

Comment: 1. They are deleted. You need to re-install them. 
2. You do need to re-install them.

Comment: And yes that is the point of a virtualenv, it means that different projects are separated and prevents conflict between different version of dependencies . By deleting a virtual env, it's like uninstalling a version of python - do you keep your packages - no.

Comment: Perhaps a better question - in which I am also interested - would be: how to efficiently work with venv: how can I make a virtual environment for my specific project, and make it portable. So that when I want to launch the project again, the required packages are installed automatically.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did try it and "import flask" and "import kivy" still work. the packages are stilled installed. I want to clear up my preconceived notion that packages installed in a virtual environment are isolated to that environment. I guess I still don't understand the whole point of a virtual environment in Python.

Comment: But were they also installed globally prior to your experiments with virtualenv? What does pip list show when you don't have an activated virtual environment?

Comment: @Ben10 in my case, "import flask" and "import kivy" in new_project still work. Maybe I installed these before creating the virtual environment, I don't remember. I will test it again tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe you may have a point. I don't remember if I installed them globally or not, I will verify and report. Thanks!

Comment: @s2000coder When you set up a virtual env use the end tag `--no-site-packages` so your virtualenv does intiate with any packages that have been installed globally

Comment: @Ben10 Thanks Ben. However, I am using venv instead of virtualenv, thus no --no-site-packages option. Also, I believe that option is deprecated. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-no-site-packages

Comment: @s2000coder Well look at that! Finally no-site-packages is done by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of Virtual Environment is to separate your development environment from your actual environment. Different projects have different package dependencies. So for these cases Virtual Environment comes in handy.

- If you installed `flask`, `kivy`, `foo`, and `bar` inside a virtual environment, then YES, you need to install them when you move into another Virtual Environment (That's the whole purpose of Virtula Environment).
- If you find that the packages are available globally then may be you are not using it correctly. You need to activate your Virtual Environment before you install anything or the packages will be installed globally.

For your case I can see you are activating before installing packages. So it should work right. you can always use `pip freeze` to see what packages are installed.

Comment: Also `pip list` lists all the packages install and their versions aswell

Comment: I installed flask and kivy without activate the venv, thus they are globally installed. I tested the whole scenario again and it's what you said. Both answers are correct, however, I pick this one as the answer because it answers specifically the two questions asked.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `pip` installs libraries into a subdirectory of the virtualenv when the env is active. Anything in there is independent of any system-wide installs, and vice versa. Removing the env obviously removes the stuff in the subdirectories.

On the other hand, virtualenv can optionally fall back to system-installed packages if you let it. The system-wide installs will obviously still be there after you remove the virtualenv.

As an aside, the current `activate` hard-codes some things so that you cannot even rename a virtualenv directory; you have to zap and reinstall it. Keeping all the things it needs in a `requirements.txt` or similar is a good way to simplify this process, as well as document the dependencies.